# Qt fullscreen application switches screens when ui is updated

Tags: qt, user-interface, screen, fullscreen

I specify the target screen and the application starts perfectly fine. As soon as the UI is updated, the application switches to the other screen (screen 1, that is located left of screen 0).

The constructor:

```
MyApp::MyApp(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MyApp)
```

Setting it to fullscreen on screen 0:

```
this->setGeometry(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(1));
this->showFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure the app window shown full screen on the same
>   monitor where the window was before making it full screen?

It is unclear which screen is which # but we can always request either screen number or even the screen rectangle immediately for `this` widget:

```
QRect rectScreen = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(this);
this->setGeometry(rectScreen); 
this->showFullScreen();
```

Comment: that is exactly what I do, the problem is that the window changes the screen once I update a label it contains

Comment: On Windows? M... this may depend on Qt version and the process DPI Awareness. Gray area. Can you try to call  ::SetProcessDPIAware(); somewhere in main() function before the application executes the event  loop and see if anything changes? Works for me but unsure if that would help you.

Comment: Ubuntu but I'll try.

Comment: Nope. That is for Windows. :-( Search for "Qt Linux monitor dpi aware". MacOS and Windows can assist. The rest? No idea.